# VPN over DX to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-direct-connect

Just wondering if the below configuration is possible or not (requirement from the security) Need to setup a VPN connection over Direct Connect to connect to the public facing services like S3. Didnt find any documentation or patterns anywhere.

If not, what is the next best practice here ?

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 is a public endpoint, which means it will not traverse your Direct Connect in a standard configuration.

If you want to use S3 (or any other AWS public endpoint) you can conside Direct Connect Public VIF. See more detail in the link below:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/public-private-interface-dx/

But all AWS public endpoints are HTTPS, so by default they are encrypted with authentication and authorization.